# Prefix route name without prefixing URI in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

I have two namespaces `'Front'` and `'Admin'`. For `'Admin'` namespace it is OK to have all paths prefixed with `admin.conrtoller.action`, but for `'Front'` I want to have prefixed route names without prefixed URIs.

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'Front'), function()
{
    Route::resource('franchising', 'FranchisingController', array('only' => array('index')));
});
```

This generates me `franchising.index` root name and `get 'franchising'` URI. How to make all resources in this group to generate route names like `front.franchising.index`, but leave current URIs without change (i.e. not prefixing it with `front/`).

I use Laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route prefix is mainly for prefixing the path. The fact that it also prefixes route names, is just an added behavior when using `Route::resource()`.

**EDIT**

It is definitely not possible with the actual prefixing, using a `prefix` route group parameter, in Laravel out of the box.

`Route::resource()` and `Route::controller()` are only a shortcuts for small amount of real use cases, where they fit. They are definitely not tools that fits for everything. If more control over routes is needed, manually specifying routes with `Route::get`, `Route::post` and such is advisable.

Comment: So it is not possible to prefix all route names within group without prefixing paths?

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use Route::get etc with much more params, but sad, because this approach is not so DRY as resource, which at once generates needed route names.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the prefix to none:

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'Front', 'prefix'=>''), function()
```

update:

You should be able to extend the Route class and override this one function:

```
class MyRoute extends \Laravel\Routing\Route {
    /**
     * Add a prefix to the route URI.
     *
     * @param  string  $prefix
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
     */
    public function prefix($prefix)
    {
        $this->uri = trim($this->uri, '/'); // removed the prefix from this line

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then use it instead of the normal route:

```
MyRoute::group(array('namespace' => 'Front'), function()
```

Update:

The extends might need to be

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class MyRoute extends Route {
```

Comment: This changes nothing. I WANT path names to have prefix, but do not want URIs to have it.

Comment: This will break how Route prefixes are intended to be used, as a whole, and will make defining routes manually far more difficult. However, if this behavior is desired, then this could be the answer.

Comment: Yes, so you would only use it on the routes you want to 'break' in this way... You can still use the normal Route class for any other routes

Comment: 'Breaking' approach is not good. As I see, the answer is "not possible out of the box".

Comment: I tried to extend Route class, but for some reason in my case i get unknown method error or unknown class error :( It seems extending route class is a tricky thing.

Comment: You might be missing an alias: In application/config/app.php, go down to Aliases and add 'MyRoute' => 'MyRoute',

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an updated answer for newcomers using at least Laravel 5.4, I'm not exactly sure when it was introduced, but you can now pass the array option `'as'` when defining routes to prefix all the route names without affecting the URI or namespace.

For example, I'm starting with a fresh laravel installation and will create the `Franchising` model.

```
php artisan make:model Franchising
```

This needs to be accessed by both a `Front` controller and an `Admin` controller.

```
php artisan make:controller --resource --model='Franchising' 'Front\FranchisingController'
php artisan make:controller --resource --model='Franchising' 'Admin\FranchisingController'
```

This creates the following files:

```
app/
├── ...
├── Franchising.php
├── Http
│   ├── Controllers
│   │   ├── Admin
│   │   │   └── FranchisingController.php
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── Front
│   │       └── FranchisingController.php
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

Create the resource routes using the `'as'` option to define route name prefixes.

```
Route::resource(
    'franchising',
    'Front\FranchisingController',
    ['as' => 'front']
);

Route::resource(
    'admin/franchising',
    'Admin\FranchisingController',
    ['as' => 'admin']
);
```

You can view all routes with artisan:

```
php artisan route:list
```

> ```
> +-----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
> | Method    | URI                                  | Name                      | Action                                                   |
> +-----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
> | GET|HEAD  | admin/franchising                    | admin.franchising.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@index   |
> | POST      | admin/franchising                    | admin.franchising.store   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@store   |
> | GET|HEAD  | admin/franchising/create             | admin.franchising.create  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@create  |
> | GET|HEAD  | admin/franchising/{franchising}      | admin.franchising.show    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@show    |
> | PUT|PATCH | admin/franchising/{franchising}      | admin.franchising.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@update  |
> | DELETE    | admin/franchising/{franchising}      | admin.franchising.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@destroy |
> | GET|HEAD  | admin/franchising/{franchising}/edit | admin.franchising.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@edit    |
> | GET|HEAD  | franchising                          | front.franchising.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Front\FranchisingController@index   |
> | POST      | franchising                          | front.franchising.store   | App\Http\Controllers\Front\FranchisingController@store   |
> | GET|HEAD  | franchising/create                   | front.franchising.create  | App\Http\Controllers\Front\FranchisingController@create  |
> | GET|HEAD  | franchising/{franchising}            | front.franchising.show    | App\Http\Controllers\Front\FranchisingController@show    |
> | PUT|PATCH | franchising/{franchising}            | front.franchising.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Front\FranchisingController@update  |
> | DELETE    | franchising/{franchising}            | front.franchising.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Front\FranchisingController@destroy |
> | GET|HEAD  | franchising/{franchising}/edit       | front.franchising.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\Front\FranchisingController@edit    |
> +-----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
> ```

Now for your specific use case, I noticed that you are only using one route on the front controller, so instead of this general solution, it might actually be better to simply define that one route.

```
Route::name('front.franchising.index')
     ->get('franchising', 'Front\FranchisingController@index');

Route::resource(
    'admin/franchising',
    'Admin\FranchisingController',
    ['as' => 'admin']
);
```

Which generates these routes:

> ```
> +-----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
> | Method    | URI                                  | Name                      | Action                                                   |
> +-----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
> | GET|HEAD  | admin/franchising                    | admin.franchising.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@index   |
> | POST      | admin/franchising                    | admin.franchising.store   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@store   |
> | GET|HEAD  | admin/franchising/create             | admin.franchising.create  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@create  |
> | GET|HEAD  | admin/franchising/{franchising}      | admin.franchising.show    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@show    |
> | PUT|PATCH | admin/franchising/{franchising}      | admin.franchising.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@update  |
> | DELETE    | admin/franchising/{franchising}      | admin.franchising.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@destroy |
> | GET|HEAD  | admin/franchising/{franchising}/edit | admin.franchising.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\FranchisingController@edit    |
> | GET|HEAD  | franchising                          | front.franchising.index   | App\Http\Controllers\Front\FranchisingController@index   |
> +-----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
> ```