# How can i use multiple prefix in against one route in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, router, prefix

Here i have used there different prefix group but there have same route. 
I get result only last prefix basis.So please help me how can i generate different prefix base url by suing same controller.

```
    Route::group(['before' => 'auth','prefix' => 'admin','middleware' => 'auth'], function($router) {
    Route::get('/advertisement', [
        'as' => 'get_advertisement_details',
        'uses' => 'AdvertisementController@getIndex',
    ]);
});

Route::group(['before' => 'auth','prefix' => 'customer','middleware' => 'auth'], function($router) {
    Route::get('/advertisement', [
        'as' => 'get_advertisement_details',
        'uses' => 'AdvertisementController@getIndex',
    ]);
});

Route::group(['before' => 'auth','prefix' => 'agent','middleware' => 'auth'], function($router) {
    Route::get('/advertisement', [
        'as' => 'get_advertisement_details',
        'uses' => 'AdvertisementController@getIndex',
    ]);
});

And i also changed the authenticate.php as below
if(Auth::user()->hasRole(ltrim($request->route()->getPrefix(),'/')))
        return $next($request);
        else
       return response('Unauthorized.', 401);

Finally i get all links(route) by agent prefix.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
$ multifun =  function () {
        Route::get('{users?}', ['uses' => 'UserController@show', 'users' => Auth::user()->id]);
};
Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], $multifun);
Route::group(['prefix' => 'me'], $multifun);
```

Comment: Sorry ,same problem.Links (route) are overwrite by last(me prefix).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158297/prefix-route-name-without-prefixing-uri-in-laravel